# FinderSync requestBadgeIdentifierForURL not invoked for new files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, findersync, osx-extensions

I have tested the template provided in Xcode for making a FinderSync Extension. For some cases the requestBadgeIdentifierForURL funciton is not invoked.

Using the finder with the view-"tree view", you can open the folder and see the files in it without double clicking or be inside the folder.

1) Moving files from one folder to another when the folder is open (you can see all the files inside the folder, like "fdgfggf2" folder see attachment) the requestBadgeIdentifierForURL function is invoked.

2) BUT when the folder is closed (like "B Sync" folder see attachment) moving the files to this folder, then is not invoked, but this is expected right? So I open the folder (showing the files, not accessing the folder like "fdgfggf2"), then the requestBadgeIdentifierForURL funciton is invoked only for the old files (that were already in the folder, not the ones that I moved).

3) Closing the folder and open it again (pressing the triangle twice) then requestBadgeIdentifierForURL function is invoked for all the files.

4) Moving the files and opening the folder (double click), only seeing the files in that specific folder, for this case requestBadgeIdentifierForURL  is invoked for all the files.

This is a expected behavior? I don't think this is bug but...Why is not invoked the first time? [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV6B1.png)

Any advice or help is appreciated

Thanks